# create dictionary from csv file using a key within row in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How would i create a dictionary using a csv file if the key is the last index (`index[9]`) in every row. for example:

```
,,,,,,,,,KEY_1
,,,,,,,,,KEY_1
,,,,,,,,,KEY_1
,,,,,,,,,KEY_2
,,,,,,,,,KEY_2
,,,,,,,,,KEY_2
,,,,,,,,,KEY_3
,,,,,,,,,KEY_3
,,,,,,,,,KEY_3
```

Is there a way to create a dictionary that would look like this:

```
dictt = {
        'KEY_1':[,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,],
        'KEY_2':[,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,],
        'KEY_3':[,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,],
        }
```

I only have 6mons of self taught python and I am working out the growing pains. Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you in advanced

Comment: Is your intent for each key in your dictionary to map to a list of lists?

Comment: @rchang the key would map to multiple lists: For KEY_1 i would have 3 lists because 3 lines have KEY_1 as `index[9]`. I want to write the lists to a csv file for each key. Would I need a list of lists for this reason?

Comment: See the answer from @AlexMartelli.  Python dictionaries map each unique key to a single object.  That object could be an iterable (for example a list), which means it in turn can contain multiple objects.  This is what Alex implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your "is it possible" question, one must say "not quite", because **no** Python construct matches the syntax you show:

```
dictt = {
    'KEY_1':[,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,],
    'KEY_2':[,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,],
    'KEY_3':[,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,],
    }
```

Entering this would be a syntax error, and **no** code can thus build the equivalent.

But if you actually mean, e.g,

```
dictt = {
    'KEY_1':[['','',,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,]],
    'KEY_2':[[,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,]],
    'KEY_3':[[,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,], [,,,,,,,,]],
    }
```

(and so on replacing each `,,` to have **something** inside, e.g an empty string -- not gonna spend a long time editing this to fix it!-), then sure, it **is** possible.

E.g:

```
import collections
import csv

dictt = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('some.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        dictt[r[-1]].append(r[:-1])
```

When this is done `dictt` will be an instance of `collections.defaultdict` (a subclass of `dict`) but you can use it as a `dict`.  Or if you absolutely insist on its being a `dict` and not a subclass thereof (though there is no conceivably good reason to thus insist), follow up with

```
dictt = dict(dictt)
```

and voila, it's converted:-)

Comment: yes, each `,,` would contain a string. i did not want to create a bloated example. for the purpose of writing all of the lists with identical keys to a csv file, i would need a list of lists?

Comment: @jes516, you need a `dict` whose values are sequences of lists of strings, and by far the simplest way to represent the latter are, indeed, lists of lists (nor can I see any advantage in choosing any other approach).

Comment: **Alex Martelli and Pyson**, just created a function to write the rows to a csv file and use the key as part of the file name. thank you once again.

Comment: is it safe to assume the list of lists `[ [], [], [] ]` will preserve the order (in which the lists where appended to list)?

Comment: @jes516 yes, a list preserves order.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
txt='''\
,,,,,,,,,KEY_1
,,,,,,,,,KEY_1
,,,,,,,,,KEY_1
,,,,,,,,,KEY_2
,,,,,,,,,KEY_2
,,,,,,,,,KEY_2
,,,,,,,,,KEY_3
,,,,,,,,,KEY_3
,,,,,,,,,KEY_3
'''

import csv

result={}
for line in csv.reader(txt.splitlines()):
    result.setdefault(line[-1], []).append(line[:-1])

>>> result
{'KEY_1': [['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], 'KEY_3': [['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], 'KEY_2': [['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]}
```